# Can Orisa's halt grab a dead Junkrat's grendades?

Tags: overwatch

So in Overwatch can Orisa use her halt to move the grenades a dying Junkrat drops? I realize it would have to be fast and fired in right direction but would such action be possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Halt doesn't affect anything but heroes, so it wouldn't affect grenades either.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with Zissouu 's answer.

> Halt doesn't affect anything but heroes

While I do not know if halt affects Junkrat's grenades, it sure does affact other things than just heroes.
Try shooting the ability in the starting area while waiting to attack. It will destroy destroyable objects and/or pull them in.
So I'm not 100% certain that it won't affect the grenades